# How to add a file path for a file input stream in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, filepath

I am using eclipse with the android adt. I am trying to initialize a file input stream, the file is in the workspace folder in the folder of my project. Now I have no idea what eclipse assumes to be the root of the project. I keep getting the file not found exception. I put the file in the src folder also and then in the src/com/.... in the folder with all the activity java files but in vain. I also tried giving the absolute path but i get an error:

```
 /C:/Users/hp/Desktop/events.ics: open failed
```

I read similar questions but somehow, its not working. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to initialize a file input stream, the file is in the workspace folder in the folder of my project.

Your development machine is not an Android device. Hence, the file is not going to be in the filesystem of an Android device.

If you wish to package files with your app, you can do so as an asset or as a raw resource. You can read more about the `assets/` and `res/raw/` project directories [in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html).

Comment: Because I am testing the app on my phone, I can just put in the file in the assets folder. But then how do i refer to that file when initializing the file input stream?

Comment: @VivekPradhan: As is stated in the documentation that I linked to, you can use `AssetManager` to access your assets: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html For example, to retrieve `assets/book/contents.json` from an `Activity` of yours, use `getAssets().open("book/contents.json");`.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare , I did not know this. File handling is quite easy in android though :P